# How to change isolation level after transaction commit

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring data over Eclipse link. I came across with a problem.
I have two methods with different transaction levels  - REPEATABLE_READ and READ_COMMITTED. Also there is third method with default transaction level.

As i understand correctly third method with default level inherits level of most recent transaction before it.

I look at logs of postgres and see that if before third transaction method with REPEATABLE_READ is being executed - third transaction has REPEATABLE_READ level, if previous transaction has READ_COMMITTED - so third has READ_COMMITTED.

This behavior is acceptable for my app. Is there way to change it? I want each transaction has it's own level without affecting others.

UPD
If i understand correctly postgres driver use **set session characteristics** for isolation level changing. Is it possible to change this behavior to using **set transaction level isolation** instead?

Comment: There is only 1 transaction, the first transactional method starts and ends the transaction all other methods participate in that. If you want to change that the other methods need `REQUIRES_NEW` as the propagation level meaning it is a new and separate transaction. You cannot change the isolation level after the transaction started.

Comment: M. Deinum, i don't wont to change the isolation level after the transaction started. I just want transaction with default level doesn't inherit isolation level of  previous transactions

Comment: You cannot as that would be changing isolation levels. There aren't different transactions there is only 1 single transaction...

Comment: M. Deinum
<Method with REPEATABLE_READ> --> <Commit>

After some time

<Method with DEFAULT LEVEL> <-- previous transaction was committed, but it affect on this one. 

<Commit>

It's two separate transactions. The aren't even concurrent. But one affects another

Comment: If that is the case I would argue that is an issue in Eclipse Link. Spring parses the transaction annotation and uses what is provided (it doesn't keep isolation levels over transactions, that only applies when one `@Transactional` is called from another `@Transactional` the outer one will be applied unless a `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation level is mentioned). So I would say that it is either an issue in Eclipse Link or the way you are using the code (which makes Spring behave in a weird way).

Comment: We are seeing the same behaviour. Having a     `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` have other methods (that just have `@Transactional`) also sometimes run with serializable isolation. Seems like the connection is not reset when it is returned to the pool.